# Escape/Bypass 404 error in Ruby (Instagram API)

Tags: ruby, http-status-code-404, instagram, cloudsight

I'm trying to get ruby to escape/bypass a 404 error but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's my code so far:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'simple_oauth'
require 'cloudsight'
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'
require 'openssl'
require 'hpricot'
require 'nokogiri'


#T FILE TO JPG

webby = 'https://t.co/5h92pCmoPM'

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

doc = Hpricot(open(webby)).to_s


jpgstart = '<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"'
jpgstop = '" />'
jpglink = doc[/#{jpgstart}(.*?)#{jpgstop}/m, 1]
print jpglink
```

This is the error I get:

```
C:/Users/User/Desktop/test89:18: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:353:in `open_http': 404 NOT FOUND (OpenURI::HTTPError)
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:724:in `buffer_open'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `block in open_loop'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `catch'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `open_loop'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:149:in `open_uri'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:704:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:34:in `open'
    from C:/Users/KVadher/Desktop/test89:20:in `<main>'
[Finished in 2.7s with exit code 1]
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could bypass the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'simple_oauth'
require 'cloudsight'
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'
require 'openssl'
require 'hpricot'
require 'nokogiri'


#T FILE TO JPG

webby = 'https://t.co/5h92pCmoPM'

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

begin
  doc = Hpricot(open(webby)).to_s

  jpgstart = '<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"'
  jpgstop = '" />'
  jpglink = doc[/#{jpgstart}(.*?)#{jpgstop}/m, 1]

  print jpglink
rescue OpenURI::HTTPError
  # do nothing. bypass error.
end
```